# Combine 3 string arraylists

Tags: android, arraylist

First of all Happy New Year to everyone, best wishes.

I have a question. Suppose I have 3 string arraylists:

```java
String group_names[] = { "Groupe A", "Groupe B", "Groupe C",
           "Groupe D", "Groupe E" };

String country_names[] = { "Brazil", "Mexico", "Croatia", "Cameroon",
           "Netherlands", "Chile", "Spain", "Australia", "Colombia" };

String country_values[] = { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4",
           "Value5", "Value6", "Value7", "Value8", "Value9" };
```

Is it possible to get the output to be like this?

Thank you in advance.

- **Groupe A**
- Brazil - Value1
- Mexico - Value2
- Croatia - Value3
- **Groupe B**
- Cameroon - Value4
- Netherlands - Value5
- **Groupe C**
- Chile - Value6
- Spain - Value7
- **Groupe D**
- Australia - Value8
- **Groupe E**
- Colombia - Value9

Already tried a `for` loop but it`s not working for me.

```java
public ArrayList<Group> SetStandardGroups() {
    //.... 
    // The 3 arraylists
    ArrayList<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();
    ArrayList<Child> ch_list;
    int size = 5;
    int j = 0;
    for (String group_name : group_names) {
        Group gru = new Group();
        gru.setName(group_name);
        ch_list = new ArrayList<Child>();
        for (; j < size; j++) {
            for (String i : country_names) {
                Child ch = new Child();
                ch.setName(country_names[j]);
                ch.setValue(country_values[j]);
                ch_list.add(ch);
            }
        }
        gru.setItems(ch_list);
        list.add(gru);
        size = size + 1;
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: You model does not contain any information regarding the country to group connection. Besides that, `j` is never set to 0 (or any other value), so you iterate over it in the first group then all the groups will be empty because the `for` loop's condition is *false*.

Comment: Hi Gergely, I try to create a custom ExpandableListView following this: http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/07/custom-expandable-listview-image-text.html I just replace the imageview for a second Textview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is to show two `textView` side by side in child view (instead of image and text), you don't need to loop through `country_names` at all.

Just update your `getChildView()` as,

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

    Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) 
    {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item, null);
    }
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value);

    tv1.setText(child.getName().toString());
    tv2.setText(child.getValue().toString());

    return convertView;
}
```

With an assumption that your `child_item.xml` would be something like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/country_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT** After your comment,I think you need to supply an array of sizes for each of you group. say,

```
int group_sizes[] = { 3, 2, 2, 1, 1};
```

And your code from question i would rewrite as,

```
public ArrayList<Group> SetStandardGroups() 
{
    //....
    // The 3 arraylists
    ArrayList<Group> list = new ArrayList<Group>();
    ArrayList<Child> ch_list;
    int size = 0, i = -1, j = 0;
    for (String group_name : group_names) 
    {
        i++;
        size = size + group_sizes[i];
        Group gru = new Group();
        gru.setName(group_name);
        ch_list = new ArrayList<Child>();
        for (; j < size; j++) 
        {
            Child ch = new Child();
            ch.setName(country_names[j]);
            ch.setValue(country_values[j]);
            ch_list.add(ch);
        }
        gru.setItems(ch_list);
        list.add(gru);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Hope this addresses all issues listed.

Comment: Hi Biju Parvathy, thx for the answer. Indeed I have child_item.xml like you described but the main problem is how to get the values to be set correctly. Groupe A contains more values as Groupe B. You understand what I mean?

Comment: @Simon, Yes I have noticed it. Your example is doing it with a fixed size of 4 with all. If you need each group to have variable sizes, do you have any specific list/array for items per each group [say, {3,2,2,1,1}]?. Please confirm, will edit my answer. Thank You.

Comment: my 3 arraylists are the exact as stated in the question.
Do you mean that? Thx again for trying to help.

Comment: @Simon How do you know the relation between those items? Your model is wrong because it doesn't contain this essential information. Try using a different model structure, like JSON, then parse it with either the native [JSON solutions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) or with an external library (like [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)).

Comment: @Simon, hope the latest edit will help you. it's a temporary fix though, I would second Gergely, if you are asking this for a project purpose than a hobby trial.

Comment: @Biju Parvathy, many thx but i get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5 on line "size = size + group_sizes[i];"
It`s not an official project, just a hobby trial as you mentioned.

Comment: @Simon, Oops, my mistake, updated now. please try latest.